# Chromium Edge password management

Tags: password, microsoft-edge

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck1Ex.png)

We have enabled the option "offer to save passwords" in Chromium Edge and due to this users are getting a pop-up with **save** or **Never** while logging into websites. However, we want to restrict the users for a specific site to not to save the password i.e while accessing one site users shouldn't be getting any pop-up to save the password. I have tried checking different blogs and MS documentation for Chromium Edge policies but couldn't find any useful information. Is there any way to restrict like this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to expand your search to also include information about Google Chrome and Chromium itself as it's quite likely that the available policies are the same across the board. However, I suspect that you are right that it's only the password saving functionality that is available as a toggle rather than any site-by-site setting. That said, what is the reason not to allow saving some specific passwords? Would a real password manager be a better solution?

Comment: Thank you for your response Hakan. 
Chromium Edge is the default and standard supported browser in our environment. Its the requirement for one application and the support team don't want to have the option to save the password.  We already have 2 different password manager solutions (PAM and Keepass) in place and this is specific to Chromium Edge

Comment: Just to be clear, I did not suggest that you switch browsers, only that you may want to also see if there is any information about such policies for the browser that Chromium-based Edge was recently forked from, as they are for the most part the same and quite likely have the same policies available.